# Filter away obj in array with null values

Tags: javascript

I would like to filter away the objects in my array of objects that has `null` or `""` values.

```js
let data = [{
  "name": "Product 2",
  "link": "/stock/product2",
  "category": "234",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 1",
  "link": "/stock/product1",
  "category": "1231",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "",
  "link": null,
  "ticker": "",
  "description": ""
}]

data = data.filter(cv => (cv.name === "" && cv.link === null));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

As you can see above I currently get the false object back. I would like to get back:

```
{
  "name": "Product 2",
  "link": "/stock/product2",
  "category": "234",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 1",
  "link": "/stock/product1",
  "category": "1231",
  "description": ""
}
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can there be any case where values other than `name` and `link` holds value `null or ""` and what should be output in such case

Answer (score 6):

Because [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) doesn't work as you think, it keeps elements that meet the condition, so invert your condition and it should work as expected:

```js
let data = [{
  "name": "Product 2",
  "link": "/stock/product2",
  "category": "234",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 1",
  "link": "/stock/product1",
  "category": "1231",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "",
  "link": null,
  "ticker": "",
  "description": ""
}]

data = data.filter(cv => !(cv.name === "" || cv.link === null));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there even a better approach as using filter?

Comment: @Anna.Klee I can't think of a better and shorter approach that this. I think `filter` is the appropriate solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will filter out items which have at least one field with `null` or `""` value.

```js
let data = [{
  "name": "Product 2",
  "link": "/stock/product2",
  "category": "234",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 1",
  "link": "/stock/product1",
  "category": "1231",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "",
  "link": null,
  "ticker": "",
  "description": ""
}]

data = data.filter(cv => Object.values(cv).some(v => v == '' || v == null));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: This does exactly what question asks for +1

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "Product 2",
    "link": "/stock/product2",
    "category": "234",
    "description": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Product 1",
    "link": "/stock/product1",
    "category": "1231",
    "description": ""
  }, {
    "name": "",
    "link": null,
    "ticker": "",
    "description": ""
  }
]
data = data.filter(cv => (cv.name && cv.link));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the values of the objects and check if some value is truty, then keep this object, otherwise filter it out.

```js
let data = [{ name: "Product 2", link: "/stock/product2", category: "234", description: "" }, { name: "Product 1", link: "/stock/product1", category: "1231", description: "" }, { name: "", link: null, ticker: "", description: "" }]

data = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(Boolean));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: `null` or `""` not all the falsy values, this will remove all the the values even if there's any other falsy value is present such as `0, false, undefined`